# busybox start init script after bootup

Tags: embedded-linux, init, busybox, pppd, runlevel

i am running an embedded linux device with busybox. after boot i want to start the ppp connection and do other things. i want to run it when everything else has finished and the system is up.

my inittab looks like:

```
::sysinit:/bin/sh /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit
::once:/bin/sh /flash/scripts/init.sh
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
```

the script is executed and pppd get started but it fails. if i run the command manually after bootup, there is no problem at all. so i thought maybe its the runlevel?

Comment: What happens when your script is invoked from the `/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit` script (where daemons are normally started)?  Have you tried to get details as to why *pppd* "fails"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your ppp daemon is dependent on something that gets started in rc.sysinit, and it tries to startup up before that dependency has completed loading.  Take sawdust's suggestion - start your init.sh script (ppp) from rc.sysinit after everything else finishes.